# How to use Jackson to parse a json in http servlet?

Tags: json, jackson

I send a json from page to server with YUI and how to get data from json in servlet. I use jackson lib 2.4. Thanks!!!

```
var user = {
                   userName:   username,
                   password:   password,
                   customerId: customerId
                  };

           new Y.IO().send("http://localhost:7778/MyController", {
                method: 'POST',
                data: user
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

actually, when you make a request like this

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.14.1/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
<script>
var user = {
        userName:   'x1',
        password:   'y2',
        customerId: 'z3'
       };
YUI().use('io-form', function (Y) {
    new Y.IO().send("http://localhost:8080/web/MyController", {
        method: 'POST',
        data: user
    });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

you're not sending a JSON object to the servlet. Instead, you're creating a http request where each property of your javascript object (which is represented in the JSON format) is sent as an http POST property, so you can retrieve these values like this

```
package mine;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class MyController
 */
@WebServlet("/MyController")
public class MyController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public MyController() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Map<String, String[]> map = request.getParameterMap();
        for(Entry<String,String[]> entry:map.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(entry.getKey());
            System.out.println(entry.getValue()[0]);
        }
    }

}
```

which in turn prints this

```
userName
x1
password
y2
customerId
z3
```

so you don't need jackson to parse the data you retrieve from your page.

Comment: Your answer is helpful. Thank you so much!